# how to use a costume emoji on a awaiting reaction?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I did this but when i put a custom emoji it doesn't work, it only works with unicode emojis.

```
message.react('707879839943753758').then(() => message.react(''));

const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return ['707879839943753758', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
};

message.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
    .then(collected => {
        const reaction = collected.first();

        if (reaction.emoji.name === '707879839943753758') {
            message.reply('report something');
        } else {
            message.reply('did not report anything');
        }
    })
    .catch(collected => {
        message.reply('you reacted with neither a thumbs up, nor a thumbs down.');
    });
```

what do i need to change in order for this to work??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `get()` the custom emoji before using it by accessing the `client`'s `emojis` collection and getting the custom emoji:

```js
const customEmoji = client.emojis.cache.get('707879839943753758');

message.react(customEmoji).then(() => message.react(''));

const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return user.id === message.author.id;
};

message.awaitReactions(filter, {
        max: 1,
        time: 60000,
        errors: ['time']
    })
    .then(collected => {
        const reaction = collected.first();

        if (reaction.emoji.id === customEmoji.id) {
            message.reply('report something');
        }
        if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
            message.reply('did not report anything');
        }
    })
    .catch(collected => {
        message.reply('you reacted with neither a thumbs up, nor a thumbs down.');
    });
```

Comment: hey @Syntle everything worked except for that part where it needs to send a message once a user reacts to the costume emoji. It doesn't give me any errors it just doesn't send/reply anything.

Comment: still doesn't for me, try doing it yourself if you can and let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: Try it once more, it's most likely my fault. Check my edit.

Comment: i just tried it right now and it still doesn't work, only the thumbs down works but not the costume emoji.

Comment: That should work, I removed the emoji part of the filter and I improved your emoji check inside the collector